# Checking Jaynes' formula 6.108 for $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty{m+a \choose m} m^nx^m$

Tags: statistics, taylor-expansion, self-learning

I read about this equation,
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty{m+a \choose m} m^nx^m = (x\frac{d}{dx})^n\frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+1}} 
\;\;\;(|x| < 1)\;\;\; (6.108)$$
As far as i know, $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty{m+a \choose m}x^m = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+1}}, \; \; \; (|x| <1 ). $$
This can be proved by the Taylor series which expands $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+1}} \;$ at x = 0.
And the (6.108) equation may be an error. Help, Thanks.

Comment: Why invoke an error in (6.108) by citing *another formula*? Or did you miss the part $$\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n$$ in the RHS of (6.108)?

Comment: Hi, what does the $ (x \frac{d}{dx})^n$ mean?, I can't get where does the $m^n$ come from.

Comment: You see? Next time, when you do not understand a part of an identity, please avoid simply making as if it was not there... In the present case, the notation is rather self-explanatory, for example, $$\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2f(x)=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(xf'(x)\right)=x(xf''(x)+f'(x))$$

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with that symbol. @Did

Comment: The formula that Jaynes provides in 6.108 is undoubtedly correct but unnecessary for 6.109.  There is no term equivalent to $m^n$ in 6.109.  Your series expansion of $(1-x)^{-(a+1)}$ is all we need for 6.109.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked the details fully, but it looks reasonable to me. For the sake of intuition, let's assume that we can move the derivative through the infinite sum. Take the second expression and differentiate it once wrt $x$, then multiply by $x$. This gives a factor $m$ and decreases the power of $x$ by one, but then increases it back when multiplying by $x$. More precisely,
$$ x \cdot \frac{d}{dx} x^m = x \cdot m x^{m-1} = m x^m. $$
So, informally, we see that the 'operator' $x (d/dx)$ when applied to $x^m$ acts as scalar multiplying by $m$. Hence if you do this $m$ times to each term in the series, the you get the desired result.

Hopefully that clears up any issues! :)